# Check if N sections intersect

Tags: c#, function, intersection, directions

folks! I need to implement the function **static bool CheckSectionsIntersect** that checks if the sections intersect (right → ; left ←; down ↓;
up ↑). Given a list of N consecutive vertical and horizontal sections of fixed dimensions in a form of a succession of directions. I have to think that I would have a route of N sections.
The function should return True if I get to a point I've been to before.
For example:

N = 6: { up, left, down, down, right, up} - return True.

```
⬇⬅
⬇⬆  <- Start
➡⬆
```

N = 4: {down, left, up, left} - return False.

```
⬅⬇  <- Start
⬆⬅
```

The code I wrote, but is incomplete because I need some suggestion to how should be the function:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        int numberOfSections = Convert.ToInt32(userInput);
        string[] sectionDirection = new string[numberOfSections];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++)
        {
            sectionDirections[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(CheckSectionsIntersect(sectionDirection, numberOfSections));
    }

    static bool CheckSectionsIntersect(string[] sectionDirection, int numberOfSections)
    {
        return true; // I need an implementation here
    }
}
```

}

May I have any suggestion for this implementation, please?
Thank you very much!

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are saying.
If you want to see if you end in a place where you have been, just make an array of tuples. In each move save your coordinates (starting form 0,0). At the end of the path check if your coordinates are in the array. Or at the end of each move that if you want to check for places where you have already been.

**Edit:**

```
static bool CheckSectionsIntersect(string[] sectionDirection, int numberOfSections)
    {
        (int X, int Y) pos = (0, 0); //Variable to track our actual position. Start position (0,0)
        List<(int X, int Y)> coordinates = new List<(int X, int Y)>(); //List where we are going to keep the coordinates
        foreach (string move in sectionDirection) //for each move
        {
            coordinates.Add(pos); //Add our current position to the list
            switch (move)         //Make a move
            {
                case "left":
                    pos.X -= 1;
                    break;
                case "right":
                    pos.X += 1;
                    break;
                case "down":
                    pos.Y -= 1;
                    break;
                case "up":
                    pos.Y += 1;
                    break;
            }
            if (coordinates.Contains(pos)) { return true; } //If our new position is already in the list, we have been there.
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I have tested it and it works.
For this purpose it is easier use a list than an array. This is due the methods .Add() an .contains().

This code is not the strongest one (for example it doesn't accept Upper letters). But since you are a beginner it should be enough. I encourage you to improve it to keep learning.

Comment: Raulmd, you got it right, I want to see if I end in a place where I have been.

Comment: I have tried to write the code following your suggestion, but without success. I can't understand how to write the moves. can you help me with that? thank you!

Comment: No problem, I have edited the answer with an example

Comment: If you want to check just the endpoint. Put the "if" out of the foreach.

Comment: If your question is nicely answered, check as solution one of the answers. This way the post would be (solved).

Answer (score 1):

If you think  of a cartesian grid, and you start at 0,0 with a left/right incrementing/decrementing the x coordinate and an up/down the y coordinate, then the answer is do you go back past 0,0 at any point.

```
static Dictionary<string,(int X,int Y)> transforms = new Dictionary<string, (int X, int Y)>{
    ["U"] = (0,1),
    ["D"] = (0,-1),
    ["L"] = (-1,0),
    ["R"] = (1,0)
};

static bool CheckSectionsIntersect(string[] sectionDirection, int numberOfSections)
{
    (int X, int Y) pos = (0,0);
    for(var i = 0;i<numberOfSections;i++)
    {
        if(!transforms.TryGetValue(sectionDirection[i], out var transform))
           throw new ArgumentException("sectionDirections");
        pos.X += transform.X;
        pos.Y += transform.Y;
        if(pos.X == 0 && pos.Y == 0)
            return true;                
    }
    return false;
}
```

Live example with your 2 test cases: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p5JY61

The above only checks that you end up back at 0,0 - however if you want to determine if you enter any co-ordine you have been to previously you simply need to keep track of where you've been using a collection and instead of checking whether you're back at 0,0 check if you're anywhere you've been before.

```
static bool CheckSectionsIntersect(string[] sectionDirection, int numberOfSections)
{
    (int X, int Y) pos = (0,0);
    var visited = new List<(int X, int Y)>{ pos };
    for(var i = 0;i<numberOfSections;i++)
    {
        if(!transforms.TryGetValue(sectionDirection[i], out var transform))
           throw new ArgumentException("sectionDirections");
        (int X, int Y) newPos = (pos.X + transform.X, pos.Y + transform.Y);
        
        if(visited.Contains(newPos))
            return true;    
                    
        pos = newPos;
        visited.Add(newPos);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FyJYrr

Comment: For non Starting point sections. Add the coords in a hashset, if the new value is already in it return true;

Comment: That covers only intersection of the starting point. May I edit your answer with intersection on any points https://dotnetfiddle.net/wkEs3l. Adding just `var existing = new HashSet<(int,int)>{pos};`
and 
`if( !existing.Add(pos)) return true;` . As it's 100% your code with just one line of new code.

Comment: @DragandDrop I have no problem _in principle_ of you editing my answer. You don't even need my permission - it's how SE works! But I might argue that we don't know if that is an actual requirement and as such might just be overcomplicating. As _another_ answer (or a second code block in this one) I think it's fine and you're welcome to take inspiration from my code if you like.

Comment: @SimonaM. can you confirm whether this answer is complete - are you trying to determine if you end back at the start, or end in any place where you have previously been? Your `true` example/testcase ends back at the start.

Comment: @Jamiec, I need to determine if  I end in a place where I have been.
I am a beginner and I haven't learned yet about dictionary in my course and how to raise an exception. I am trying to find another solution using arrays. Any suggestions are welcome.